# Emacs lisp: How can I get the newest file in a directory?

Tags: file, emacs, directory, elisp

Given the path of a directory, how can I return the path of the newest file in that directory?

Answer (score 7):

Using built-in APIs can achieve as well:

```
(defun latest-file (path)
  "Get latest file (including directory) in PATH."
  (car (directory-files path 'full nil #'file-newer-than-file-p)))

(latest-file "~/.emacs.d") ;; => "/Users/xcy/.emacs.d/var"
```

If you also needs files under sub-directory, use `directory-files-recursively` rather than `directory-files`. If you want to exclude directories, filter the file/directory list first by using `file-directory-p`.

Comment: note that this algorithm requires `N*log(N)* disk accesses, where `N` is the number of files in the directory.

Comment: @sds I've updated my answer by using `directory-files` directly instead of sorting myself.

Comment: `file-newer-than-file-p` accesses disk twice.

Comment: I see, should use `directory-files-and-attributes`

Comment: In emacs 26.1, the help for `directory-files` claims that specifying the 4th argument results in an unsorted list, which  `nil` or unspecified sorts by `string-lessp`.

Comment: This function does not seem to use the file attributes, time `file-attribute-modification-time` and does not return the files last modified in the directory. The function provided by @avidj works best for me.

Comment: @RudigerWolf file-newer-than-file-p does use Last modification time.

Answer (score 3):

Using [f](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el):

```
(defun aj-fetch-latest (path)
  (let ((e (f-entries path)))
    (car (sort e (lambda (a b)
                   (not (time-less-p (aj-mtime a)
                                     (aj-mtime b))))))))
(defun aj-mtime (f) (let ((attrs (file-attributes f))) (nth 5 attrs)))
```

Comment: This works in Emacs 26.1, assuming you have F installed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without dependencies

- `directory-files-and-attributes` gives us a list of files and directories with attributes

  - the 4th arg `NOSORT` is a bool and does not take a function as the top answer suggests

  > (directory-files-and-attributes DIRECTORY &optional FULL MATCH NOSORT
  > ID-FORMAT)
  > If NOSORT is non-nil, the list is not sorted--its order is unpredictable.
  > NOSORT is useful if you plan to sort the result yourself.

  - attributes are in the format of `file-attributes` - which gives us the modification time and whether the item is a file or directory

  > 0. t for directory, string (name linked to) for symbolic link, or nil.\
  > 1. Last modification time, likewise.  This is the time of the last

```lisp
(car
 (seq-find
  '(lambda (x) (not (nth 1 x))) ; non-directory
  (sort
   (directory-files-and-attributes path 'full nil t)
   '(lambda (x y) (time-less-p (nth 5 y) (nth 5 x)))))) ; last modified first: y < x
```